# Refrigerator pickles in plastic?

Tags: storage-method, pickling, asparagus

This year I'm going to try my hand at pickling. I've found recipes for asparagus refrigerator pickles that sound good, but they all say to use mason jars. I have a number of plastic containers that are of a perfect size and shape. Is there a good reason to use glass rather than plastic for refrigerator pickles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advantages of glass:  you can see the product....the container does not pick up any flavor or color from the product...other than that, in this case (refrigerator pickle) there is no reason not to use your plastic.  In fact, the only reason to use glass, that I can think of, is if you we going to can your pickles for extended shelf life. Then, of course, would would need Mason jars or equivalent.  Fermenting, doesn't have much to do with this question either.  I often store homemade sauerkraut and kimchee in plastic quart containers without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Clemson University Extension](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/food/food_safety/preservation/hgic3101.html):

> Can I ferment pickles in a new plastic garbage can?
>
> The plastic needs to be food-grade. Pickles and sauerkraut can be
>   fermented in large stoneware crocks, large glass jars or food-grade
>   plastic containers.

Since fermenting is usually longer term and very acidic, and since many food products are sold in plastic containers, one can reasonably infer that you are fine as long as the containers are food safe plastic.

Comment: Are refrigerator pickles usually fermented? The recipes I've seen are just pickled and eaten after as little as a few hours.

Comment: No, they aren't but since they have less stringent requirements than the true fermented...